# how to convert integer minutes to interval in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I'm trying to convert minutes which are in integer to interval in postgres

Is there any function that will help me to convert it to interval or should i have divide it by 60 and get the final result

```
20 minutes will be like 00:20:00 as result
```

Comment: You should flag this and move it to [dba.se]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Fastest way is with `make_interval`

```
make_interval(years int DEFAULT 0, months int DEFAULT 0, weeks int DEFAULT 0, days int DEFAULT 0, hours int DEFAULT 0, mins int DEFAULT 0, secs double precision DEFAULT 0.0)
```

So it looks like this (as suggested by @Teddy)

```
SELECT make_interval(mins => 20);
```

or,

```
SELECT make_interval(0,0,0,0,0,20);
```

Not to say that's the cleanest, if speed isn't an issue I prefer the `*` method @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned

```
SELECT 20 * '1 minute'::interval;
```

Comment: Why not simply `make_interval(mins := 20)`?

Answer (score 15):

you can concat that integer with `' minutes'`:

```
t=# with i as (
  select 20::int n
)
select concat(n,' minutes')::interval 
from i;
  concat
----------
 00:20:00
(1 row)

Time: 1.220 ms
```

**Update**:

Or: `interval '1' minute * n` as a_horse_with_no_name says

Comment: I chose this one and used a shorter form of concatenation:
`select (n||' minutes')::interval`

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are trying to insert data in an `interval` column, you can use integer seconds and PostgreSQL will convert it to a interval.

Comment: Unfortunately am getting this: ERROR Database error 22015: interval field value out of range: "86400000000"