# Substitute SQL parameter with ? is not working inside single quote( ' )

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am trying to run query using SqlExecuter by replacing the placeholder(?) inside single quote for below SQL

SQL: SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - interval '? hours' GROUP BY name;

Java code i am trying to replace the parameter

```
Integer hourCount = 72; //String type also did not work
SQL_QUERY = "SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - interval '? hours' GROUP BY name;"
Map<String, Integer> scoreCount = new HashMap<>();
SqlExecutor sqlExecutor = new SqlExecutor(dbConfig);
scoreCount = sqlExecutor.executeForResultSet(SQL_QUERY, resultSet -> {
    Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        results.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getInt(2));
    }
    return results;
}, hourCount);
```

I am getting below exception for above code snippet

```
09/Nov/2020 20:47:05:271 [ajp-apr-127.0.0.1-8019-exec-5] ERROR  com.xyz.admin.utils.abc getScoreCount  - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:56)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setBinaryParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:122)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindBytes(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2312)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setInt(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1900)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gStatement.setObject(AbstractJdbc3gStatement.java:36)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc4Statement.java:48)
```

On checking online for the problem, based on https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/932,
it suggested to pass entire string content inside the single quote as parameter as below. Also referred that while constructing the query, PreparedStatement will automatically add quotes around the passed parameters

```
String hourCount = 72;
sqlExecutor.executeForResultSet("SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - interval ? GROUP BY name;", resultSet -> {
    Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        results.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getInt(2));
    }
    return results;
}, hourCount + " hours");
```

This resulted in below error

```
09/Nov/2020 21:21:56:594 [ajp-apr-127.0.0.1-8019-exec-2] ERROR  com.xyz.tips.admin.utils.abc getScoreCount  - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 84
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 84
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)
        at com.avenda.tips.utils.sql.AbstractJdbcOperations$3.run(AbstractJdbcOperations.java:64)
        at com.avenda.tips.utils.sql.AbstractJdbcOperations$2.run(AbstractJdbcOperations.java:46)
        at com.avenda.tips.utils.sql.SqlExecutor.execute(SqlExecutor.java:32)
        at com.avenda.tips.utils.sql.AbstractJdbcOperations.execute(AbstractJdbcOperations.java:40)
        at com.avenda.tips.utils.sql.AbstractJdbcOperations.executeForResultSet(AbstractJdbcOperations.java:59)
```

Since both of the above did not work, i am passing pre-formatted sql string using

```
SQL_QUERY = "SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - interval '? hours' GROUP BY name;"
SQL_QUERY.replace("?", hourCount)
```

Can i know what i am missing here and how to avoid sql injection when query contains single quote as above?

Comment: Maybe try using the `make_interval()` function? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656783/how-to-convert-integer-minutes-to-interval-in-postgres

Comment: You can't use bind variable for interval as it takes string literal. Replace it with make_interval() as suggested above so you can use bind variable. Your method of using pre-formatted may work but it not recommended it is maybe susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: make_interval() will serve the purpose to avoid using single quotes. Thanks! Final SQL
` SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - make_interval(hours => 200) GROUP BY name; `

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a question mark inside a string literal is not treated as a parameter and is not replaced.

Try this:

```java
SQL_QUERY = "SELECT name, sum(marks) FROM scores WHERE datetime >= now() - interval '1 hour' * ? GROUP BY name;"
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks! Found alternative solution with make interval function as well.